# Objective-C - Unloading loaded view when it is swapped

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the best way to do view management in a multiview application?

Right now I have this ViewSwitcher method/function that comes from a custom delegate I created.

The code is a whole bunch of if else like this

```
    MyViewController *c = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    c.delegate = self;
    self.myViewController = c;

    [self.viewHolder insertSubview:c.view atIndex:0];
    [c release];
```

That works fine, but when I visited the function a second time, is there going to be 2 instances of MyViewController now or just 1?
How do I unload MyViewController when I switch to another view?

Or is there a better way to manage my views?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: How is `myViewController` declared? Does the `[c release];` belong to the snippet above?

Comment: Ah yeah, the [c release]; was misplaced. Just fixed that. myViewController is done using @property (retain, nonatomic) in the header and @synthesize in the implementation. Thx, Tee

Answer (score 0):

If self.myViewController is a retained property, then there will be two instances of `MyViewController` up until this line:

```
self.myViewController = c;
```

... at that point the synthesized accessors will release the instances created in the first pass and then retain the newly created one. If the first instances has not been retained by another object, it will deallocate.